# HTML table -> Colspan="6" looks like "4"

Tags: html, html-table

My timetable is devided to 15 minutes. So 1 hours = 4x `<td>`  For `<td>Sparingy</td>` I set `colspan="6"` so 6x15 mins = 1.5 hour. But it look's like I set `Colspan="4"`. Of course when I set real `Colspan="4"` it behaves similarly.

"sparingy" ends at 19:30 (7:30PM) and there is still 1.5 hour to 21:00 (9:00PM) so 1.5 hour/15 minutes = 6. It means I must left 6x <td> behind.

For better view I also insert image where should be everything clear to see.
[image]

Honestly i don't know what's the problem. I'd like to do it in Grid but it will be used in WordPress and timetable will manage another person without knowledge of anything about HTML.

```css
th {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table class="demo">
  <caption>
    Table 1
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="time"></th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">6:00 - 7:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">7:00 - 8:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">8:00 - 9:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">9:00 - 10:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">10:00 - 11:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">11:00 - 12:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">12:00 - 13:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">13:00 - 14:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">14:00 - 15:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">15:00 - 16:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">16:00 - 17:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">17:00 - 18:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">18:00 - 19:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">19:00 - 20:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">20:00 - 21:00</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Pondělí</td>
      <td colspan="48">Soukromé lekce a večejnost po domlivě</td>
      <td class="kondicni" colspan="4">
        Kondiční <br /> kickbox
      </td>
      <td class="box" colspan="6">Box</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Úterý</td>
      <td colspan="38">Soukromé lekce a večejnost po domlivě</td>
      <td class="kickbox6" colspan="4">
        Kickbox děti <br /> 6 - 10 let
      </td>
      <td class="kickbox10" colspan="5">
        Kickbox děti <br /> 10 - 15 let
      </td>
      <td class="mma" colspan="5">MMA</td>
      <td class="zavodnici" colspan="6">K1 - závodníci</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Středa</td>
      <td colspan="44">Soukromé lekce a večejnost po domlivě</td>
      <td class="rodice" colspan="4">
        Rodiče a děti<br /> 3 - 6 let
      </td>
      <td class="kondicni" colspan="4">
        Kondiční <br /> kickbox
      </td>
      <td class="box" colspan="6">Box</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Čtvrtek</td>
      <td colspan="38">Soukromé lekce a večejnost po domlivě</td>
      <td class="kickbox6" colspan="4">
        Kickbox děti <br /> 6 - 10 let
      </td>
      <td class="kickbox10" colspan="5">
        Kickbox děti <br /> 10 - 15 let
      </td>
      <td class="mma" colspan="5">MMA</td>
      <td class="zavodnici" colspan="6">K1 - závodníci</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Pátek</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="6">Sparingy</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Sobota</td>
      <td colspan="60">Pronájem, semináře, akce, atd...</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Neděle</td>
      <td colspan="60">Pronájem, semináře, akce, atd...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

```
Edit: CSS
  .demo {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  }
  .demo th {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  .demo td {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: Can you share your css as well

Comment: Normally collapses widths when you do not have hardcoded sizes.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the "missing" columns are there but they don't have a real size. So when you add a size in your style like:

```
td { width: 15px }
```

Yeah, that's assuming each cell of your 61 cells needs the same space.

But you could also give your first column more space. Then you should be fine. I hope it helps.

```css
th {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table class="demo">
  <caption>
    Table 1
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="time"></th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">6:00 - 7:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">7:00 - 8:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">8:00 - 9:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">9:00 - 10:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">10:00 - 11:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">11:00 - 12:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">12:00 - 13:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">13:00 - 14:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">14:00 - 15:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">15:00 - 16:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">16:00 - 17:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">17:00 - 18:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">18:00 - 19:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">19:00 - 20:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">20:00 - 21:00</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Pondělí</td>
      <td colspan="48">Soukromé lekce a večejnost po domlivě</td>
      <td class="kondicni" colspan="4">
        Kondiční <br /> kickbox
      </td>
      <td class="box" colspan="6">Box</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Úterý</td>
      <td colspan="38">Soukromé lekce a večejnost po domlivě</td>
      <td class="kickbox6" colspan="4">
        Kickbox děti <br /> 6 - 10 let
      </td>
      <td class="kickbox10" colspan="5">
        Kickbox děti <br /> 10 - 15 let
      </td>
      <td class="mma" colspan="5">MMA</td>
      <td class="zavodnici" colspan="6">K1 - závodníci</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Středa</td>
      <td colspan="44">Soukromé lekce a večejnost po domlivě</td>
      <td class="rodice" colspan="4">
        Rodiče a děti<br /> 3 - 6 let
      </td>
      <td class="kondicni" colspan="4">
        Kondiční <br /> kickbox
      </td>
      <td class="box" colspan="6">Box</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Čtvrtek</td>
      <td colspan="38">Soukromé lekce a večejnost po domlivě</td>
      <td class="kickbox6" colspan="4">
        Kickbox děti <br /> 6 - 10 let
      </td>
      <td class="kickbox10" colspan="5">
        Kickbox děti <br /> 10 - 15 let
      </td>
      <td class="mma" colspan="5">MMA</td>
      <td class="zavodnici" colspan="6">K1 - závodníci</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Pátek</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="6">Sparingy</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Sobota</td>
      <td colspan="60">Pronájem, semináře, akce, atd...</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Neděle</td>
      <td colspan="60">Pronájem, semináře, akce, atd...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table has 61 columns according to the header row. It's critical that all other rows have the same number of cells.

The second thing is that since your heading cells have colspans the individual cells have no basis for size. One solution might be to include a hidden row of individual cells. This establishes individual cell size and clears up some width calculation issues. Spanned cells come closer to what you'd hope to see.

```css
th {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.hidden th {
  height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="demo">
  <caption>
    Table 1
  </caption>

  <thead>
    <tr class="hidden" aria-hidden="true">
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th class="time"></th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">6:00 - 7:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">7:00 - 8:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">8:00 - 9:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">9:00 - 10:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">10:00 - 11:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">11:00 - 12:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">12:00 - 13:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">13:00 - 14:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">14:00 - 15:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">15:00 - 16:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">16:00 - 17:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">17:00 - 18:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">18:00 - 19:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">19:00 - 20:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">20:00 - 21:00</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Čtvrtek</td>
      <td colspan="37">Soukromé lekce a večejnost po domlivě</td>
      <td class="kickbox6" colspan="4">
        Kickbox děti <br /> 6 - 10 let
      </td>
      <td class="kickbox10" colspan="5">
        Kickbox děti <br /> 10 - 15 let
      </td>
      <td class="mma" colspan="5">MMA</td>
      <td class="zavodnici" colspan="6">K1 - závodníci</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="day-column">Pátek</td>
      <td colspan="48">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="6">Sparingy</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
th {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table class="demo">
  <caption>
    Table 1
  </caption>

  <head>
    <tr>
      <th class="time"></th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">6:00 - 7:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">7:00 - 8:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">8:00 - 9:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">9:00 - 10:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">10:00 - 11:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">11:00 - 12:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">12:00 - 13:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">13:00 - 14:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">14:00 - 15:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">15:00 - 16:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">16:00 - 17:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">17:00 - 18:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">18:00 - 19:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">19:00 - 20:00</th>
      <th class="time" colspan="4">20:00 - 21:00</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="day-column">Pondělí</td>
        <td colspan="48">Soukromé lekce a večejnost po domlivě</td>
        <td class="kondicni" colspan="4">
          Kondiční <br /> kickbox
        </td>
        <td class="box" colspan="6">Box</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="day-column">Úterý</td>
        <td colspan="38">Soukromé lekce a večejnost po domlivě</td>
        <td class="kickbox6" colspan="4">
          Kickbox děti <br /> 6 - 10 let
        </td>
        <td class="kickbox10" colspan="5">
          Kickbox děti <br /> 10 - 15 let
        </td>
        <td class="mma" colspan="5">MMA</td>
        <td class="zavodnici" colspan="6">K1 - závodníci</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="day-column">Středa</td>
        <td colspan="44">Soukromé lekce a večejnost po domlivě</td>
        <td class="rodice" colspan="4">
          Rodiče a děti<br /> 3 - 6 let
        </td>
        <td class="kondicni" colspan="4">
          Kondiční <br /> kickbox
        </td>
        <td class="box" colspan="6">Box</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="day-column">Čtvrtek</td>
        <td colspan="38">Soukromé lekce a večejnost po domlivě</td>
        <td class="kickbox6" colspan="4">
          Kickbox děti <br /> 6 - 10 let
        </td>
        <td class="kickbox10" colspan="5">
          Kickbox děti <br /> 10 - 15 let
        </td>
        <td class="mma" colspan="5">MMA</td>
        <td class="zavodnici" colspan="6">K1 - závodníci</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="day-column">Pátek</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="6">Sparingy</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="day-column">Sobota</td>
        <td colspan="60">Pronájem, semináře, akce, atd...</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="day-column">Neděle</td>
        <td colspan="60">Pronájem, semináře, akce, atd...</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please see [answer]. Code dumps are not considered helpful. Provide some explanation of your solution.

Comment: I added some CSS so we can see better. You've included a row with too few cells, and it doesn't seem to have helped.